# How to get access to my Google Analytics data and use them on website

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, analytics

I am just building an Affiliate system for only my personal needs. I want to get the data about referral links from Google Analytics. I have bad problem with connecting them with my website.

I have already got the data through the url from Query Explorer, but the problem is that its access_token is limited only for 60 mins. I also tried to register at developers console and setting up API key and enabling the Analytics API for my website, but it doesn't work.

```
$url="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3my-analytics-id&start-date=".$_SESSION['start-date']."&end-date=".$_SESSION['end-date']."&metrics=ga%3Ausers%2Cga%3AtransactionRevenue&dimensions=ga%3Acampaign&key=AIzaSyA_7ypw-2DY4y0UZWDSmSnJBIeXXXXXXX"; /*trying to access it by given API key by key= parameter. */
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$rows = $data["rows"];
$count = sizeof($rows);

$i = 0;
while ($rows[$i][0] != $_SESSION['affil-id']) {
    $i++;
}

$visitors = $rows[$i][1];
$revenue = $rows[$i][2];
```

Everything I basically need is to get data about my referral links for my affiliate system. For example utm_campaign=partner1. I need to get partner1's number of visitors from his link and sales. He would than see the affiliate profit on his dashboard.

Comment: You need a "service account": https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply,

I saw that also, but I don't understand how to integrate OAuth2 simpy to my webpage. Also I can't be logging in every time. Users of the system should just login and see analytics for their referral.

Comment: A service account has a long-lived token. You get it once via the OAuth flow (I don't recall if there's a way to get it directly from the Google console), configure your application to use it, and it continues to use it on an ongoing basis.